# What do you call collective intelligence?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, portmanteau-words

Collective intelligence is a form of wisdom of crowds. What together an aggregation knows is often pretty comparable with expert opinions. What is one word (or at most two) that describes this kind of community knowledge?

Comment: commun knowledge or collective intelligence is fine as it is. Why looking for something more complicated ?

Comment: Looking merely for one word that can capture this essence, is all. Even if the word is a combination of two others, or a new one altogether that makes the same sense. Ambitious?

Comment: Don't expect there to be a possible one-word solution for everything (or even most things). There isn't. That said, my immediate thought when I read the title of the question was ***Borg***.

Comment: Of course, we are not always wiser in the aggregate, as recognized in the concept and studies of groupthink. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink

Answer (score 4):

You're very close; Wikipedia says the preferred term is [collective wisdom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_wisdom):

> Collective wisdom, also called group wisdom and co-intelligence, is
>   shared knowledge arrived at by individuals and groups.

This rather cuts across a classification I like:

**knowledge**: knowing what (ie basic factual knowledge)

**understanding**: understanding why (things inter-relate, work, happen)

**wisdom**: understanding how (to alter things for the better, and putting these changes into effect).

Comment: Am actually looking merely for a one-word version. Or maybe a invented word, combining two existing ones innovatively so it carries this same sense. Or even root words, maybe. 

Co-intel is not bad, but any other?

Comment: "What is one word **(or at most two)**"?

Comment: @Saugata Invented? That would take it off-topic; this website is centred on the English language as it is used.

Comment: Edwin, when I say 'invented', I mean innovative English usage like portmanteau words.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't read nohat's sound comments on meta: Requests for coinage ... this as an invitation to start coining words. I really don't feel comfortable at all with our site becoming a place where people go who want a word invented.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for ***[lore](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lore)***.

> collective knowledge or wisdom on a particular subject, esp of a traditional nature

Comment: Lore does have connotations of not necessarily being true so if you want to avoid those a quick thesaurus search with lore turns up 'doctrine' which is probably equally suitable in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

**Crowdsourcing** or '**Crowd sourcing**' is today's common usage, and is so recognized for solving  crimes/mysteries that public officials are directly appealing to enthusiasts

> "Simply defined, **[crowdsourcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowdsourcing#Definitions)** represents the act of a company or
>   institution taking a function once performed by employees and
>   outsourcing it to an undefined (and generally large) network of people
>   in the form of an open call. This can take the form of peer-production
>   (when the job is performed collaboratively), but is also often
>   undertaken by sole individuals. The crucial prerequisite is the use of
>   the open call format and the large network of potential laborers." -

Answer (score 0):

[***folk wisdom***](http://www.utexas.edu/courses/sami/diehtu/siida/language/folkevisdom.htm)

> folk wisdom: knowledge or beliefs associated with or traditional to the common people of a country